# Radio buttons grouped by a form angular

Tags: html, forms, angular, formgroups

I'm currently getting some weird functionality with radio buttons and forms.

Basically I have a form with 4 radio buttons. Right now: When I click a radio button it is permanently enabled. I can thus have all 4 options selected. Clicking the option does not deselect the radio option.

I would like it to switch between the options, so I can only have 1 option selected at a time. What am I missing?

my Code:

```
<form [formGroup]="answer" (submit)="saveAnswer()">
    <input formControlName="answer" id="option1" type="radio" />
    <input formControlName="answer2" id="option2" type="radio" />
    <input formControlName="answer3" id="option3" type="radio" />
    <input formControlName="answer4" id="option4" type="radio" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

constructor(
 private movieService: MovieService,
 private formBuilder: FormBuilder
) {
 this.answer = this.formBuilder.group({
   'answer': '',
   'answer2': '',
   'answer3': '',
   'answer4': ''
 });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want radio buttons that are "grouped" together (so you can select only one of them) you should give all of them the same name:

```
<form [formGroup]="answer" (submit)="saveAnswer()">
    <input formControlName="answer" value="answer1" id="option1" type="radio" />
    <input formControlName="answer" value="answer2" id="option2" type="radio" />
    <input formControlName="answer" value="answer3" id="option3" type="radio" />
    <input formControlName="answer" value="answer4" id="option4" type="radio" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

You can distinct between them using their `value`

Comment: Worked great! Thanks, so when I click my submit button, will it only return the selected radio button and the value attached to that button?

Comment: It might not work this way because you have javascript code there that might change this behavior, but basically yes - this is how it should work.